# Intent problem and firebase not updating values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So,basically when I will click the login button ..it should redirect me to the home page or the introduction page.but when I click the login button nothing happens .Also there is no error coming...I mean the intent is not working .
Also I have connected my App with firebase but also the data is not getting added in my firebase.

this is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plain_text_input"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="142dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="439dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_username"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="USERNAME"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtusername"
        android:layout_width="356dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="381dp"
        android:contextClickable="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Username"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="78dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="78dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="325dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_password"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="PASSWORD"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtpassword"
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/DeepPink"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="373dp"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="124dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="131dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:text="LOGIN "
                android:onClick="LOGIN"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="147dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="147dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="SIGN IN NOW"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="108dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="495dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ticket" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="598dp"
        android:text="ADMIN"
        android:textSize="20dp"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my Main_Activity.java class

this is my   MainActivity2 code

```
    public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
        RecyclerView recycleview1;
        List<String> titles;
        List<Integer>images;
        GridAdapter adapter;
    
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.intoduction);
            recycleview1 = findViewById(R.id.recycleview1);
    
            titles = new ArrayList<>();
            images = new ArrayList<>();
    
            titles.add("LATEST MOVIES");
            titles.add("UPCOMING MOVIES");
            titles.add("TRENDING MOVIES");
            titles.add("NOW PLAYING");
            titles.add("RELEASED MOVIES");
            titles.add("HINDI MOVIES");
            titles.add("MARATHI MOVIES");
            titles.add("ENGLISH MOVIES");
            titles.add("TELUGU MOVIES");
            titles.add("TAMIL MOVIES");
    
    
            images.add(R.drawable.latestmovie);
            images.add(R.drawable.upcomingmovies);
            images.add(R.drawable.trendingmovie);
            images.add(R.drawable.nowplaying);
            images.add(R.drawable.releasedmovie);
            images.add(R.drawable.hindimovies);
            images.add(R.drawable.marathimovies);
            images.add(R.drawable.englishmovies);
            images.add(R.drawable.telugumovies);
            images.add(R.drawable.tamilmovies);
    
    
            adapter =  new GridAdapter(this,titles,images);
    
            GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
            recycleview1.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
            recycleview1.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    
    
    
        }
    
    
    
    }

this is my Main_activity2 .java class
    package com.example.moviebookingapp2;
    
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
         EditText txtusername;
         EditText txtpassword;
         Button textView2;
    
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
            txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
            textView2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    
    
    
            Button textView3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewUserActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
    
    
                }
            });
    
    
    
        }
    
    
        public void LOGIN(View view) {
    
            txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
            txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
            textView2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    
            String username = txtusername.toString().trim();
            String password = txtpassword.toString().trim();
    
            dataholder obj = new dataholder(username,password);
    
            FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference root = db.getReference("user_login");
    
    
            root.child("id").setValue(obj);
    
            txtusername.setText("");
            txtusername.setText("");
    
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    
    
    
            textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
    
                    String username = txtusername.getText().toString().trim();
                    String password = txtpassword.getText().toString().trim();
                    if(username.isEmpty())
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else if(username.length()<8|| username.length()>15)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username must contain  atleast 8  characters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else if(password.isEmpty())
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else if(password.length()<6|| password.length()>10)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password must contain 6  characters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else {
                    }
                }
            });
    
    
    
        }
    }


public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recycleview1;
    List<String> titles;
    List<Integer>images;
    GridAdapter adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intoduction);
        recycleview1 = findViewById(R.id.recycleview1);

        titles = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();

        titles.add("LATEST MOVIES");
        titles.add("UPCOMING MOVIES");
        titles.add("TRENDING MOVIES");
        titles.add("NOW PLAYING");
        titles.add("RELEASED MOVIES");
        titles.add("HINDI MOVIES");
        titles.add("MARATHI MOVIES");
        titles.add("ENGLISH MOVIES");
        titles.add("TELUGU MOVIES");
        titles.add("TAMIL MOVIES");


        images.add(R.drawable.latestmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.upcomingmovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.trendingmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.nowplaying);
        images.add(R.drawable.releasedmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.hindimovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.marathimovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.englishmovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.telugumovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.tamilmovies);


        adapter =  new GridAdapter(this,titles,images);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recycleview1.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recycleview1.setAdapter(adapter);




    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added any code to login happen

```
textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String username = txtusername.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = txtpassword.getText().toString().trim();
                if(username.isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(username.length()<8|| username.length()>15)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username must contain  atleast 8  characters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(password.isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(password.length()<6|| password.length()>10)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password must contain 6  characters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    //Just add you intent here for the login to happen
                  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewUserActivity.class);
                  startActivity(i);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewUserActivity.class);
                  startActivity(i);

Comment: actually i want to open Main_Activity2 page

Comment: So this if i change NewUserActivity to Main_Activity2..then its giving me an error

Comment: I have copied the code of MainActivity2 above

Comment: and this is the error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.moviebookingapp2.MainActivity2.onCreate

Comment: Wil u please help me with this

Comment: See in your layout file of MainActivity2 that in Recycler View you have mentioned correct  Id